Receiving 403 forbidden error while loading 3rd party UI in an iframe during run of Cypress automation tool
I've been trying to automate some tests using Cypress tool. When testing there is a scenario where a 3rd party ui gets loaded inside an iframe, it throws 403 forbidden error. The functionality works fine when accessing application directly. Its only throws 403 error when running automation testing using Cypress. We have Electron as default web browser and can't use any other browser due to company policies. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

It looks like the request initiated by the Web drop-in fails because the client key is missing or incorrect. The request is something like:
https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/sessions/yyyyyy/setup?clientKey=test_xxxxxx

It is possible that the key is not picked up outside the iframe or not configured to be used by the tool.
